# How to dry up type definition of function that returns another function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've enabled the ESLint rule that forces you to specify all functions' return types. In React hooks, this leads to patterns such as the following:

```
const useSubmitForm = (): ((
  form: FormProps,
  submissions: (string | MultipleChoiceOption[])[],
  user: string
) => FormEventHandler) => {
  const notify = useNotification();
  return (
      form: FormProps,
      submissions: (string | MultipleChoiceOption[])[],
      user: string
    ): FormEventHandler =>
    (e) => {

    };
};
```

The types of the outer function's return type arguments  are identical to the inner function's arguments.

How can I dry this up so as to avoid the repetition?

Comment: Is there any chance you might elaborate on this / provide an example? The way I've been trying to do this seem to make things more complex rather than simpler.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoaxLN) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case just delete the type definitions of the function innards

```
const useSubmitForm = (): ((
  form: FormProps,
  submissions: (string | MultipleChoiceOption[])[],
  user: string
) => FormEventHandler) => {
  const notify = useNotification();
  return (
    form,
    submissions,
    user
  ): FormEventHandler =>
    (e) => {

    };
};
```

TypeScript automatically gets those types. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=6&pln=17&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsAKV0AOAzsgN7IC+A3AFCiSyIoCyArgDZjAHsQDCAC3TAkAeQJd0IMpVpgAngRQZsAUQBuEcAAk4IACa8oyALzIAFBABcaTFgAicMHA1awASlMA+ZOuH7aGgQpIjBkViIIADl0LhgRJ2ApUwtPEx9WAwh4kAgAmiCQsIiIAGVWACMsYDAVLBTzdxtzcxpkZBg7Gzq8QiIAGjbkIkrqoiIkkCJm0KhQAHNkAB9kNk5uXkFhMQlJgG0AXXdDwfaSqBtZhZo0nzrXHT1DaFuyIeCpsJBY4Bh5FJKMTiCUkIEatHaUAgYFYUGkrXa7U62FOiJGVWA40mAyGZ0iUCGTVsak0jwMRm8uIsEFepAKiNkNGoQA)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ESLint rule you have, so you *might* be able to remove the second instance of `FormEventHandler` too?

Comment: Absolutely right. Thanks again :) Got a lot of hooks to run this on